# Bazel error: type 'java_common' has no method create_provider()

Tags: scala, bazel

I've tried to create a hello world for `scala` project on `bazel`.
But got an error:

```
ERROR: /private/var/tmp/_bazel_user/4c70a1cb51cd18a4cc09dc9aa5e6a71b/external/scalac_rules_commons_io/BUILD:9:1: in scala_import rule @scalac_rules_commons_io//:scalac_rules_commons_io: 
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/private/var/tmp/_bazel_user/4c70a1cb51cd18a4cc09dc9aa5e6a71b/external/scalac_rules_commons_io/BUILD", line 9
        scala_import(name = 'scalac_rules_commons_io')
    File "/private/var/tmp/_bazel_user/4c70a1cb51cd18a4cc09dc9aa5e6a71b/external/io_bazel_rules_scala/scala/scala_import.bzl", line 27, in _scala_import_impl
        struct(<2 more arguments>)
    File "/private/var/tmp/_bazel_user/4c70a1cb51cd18a4cc09dc9aa5e6a71b/external/io_bazel_rules_scala/scala/scala_import.bzl", line 32, in struct
        _create_provider(current_jars, <6 more arguments>)
    File "/private/var/tmp/_bazel_user/4c70a1cb51cd18a4cc09dc9aa5e6a71b/external/io_bazel_rules_scala/scala/scala_import.bzl", line 73, in _create_provider
        java_common.create_provider(<5 more arguments>)
type 'java_common' has no method create_provider()
```

Project structure:

[image]

`WORKSPACE` file was copied from [here](https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_scala#getting-started)

```
rules_scala_version="69d3c5b5d9b51537231746e93b4383384c9ebcf4" # update this as needed

load("@bazel_tools//tools/build_defs/repo:http.bzl", "http_archive")
http_archive(
    name = "io_bazel_rules_scala",
    strip_prefix = "rules_scala-%s" % rules_scala_version,
    type = "zip",
    url = "https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_scala/archive/%s.zip" % rules_scala_version,
)

load("@io_bazel_rules_scala//scala:toolchains.bzl", "scala_register_toolchains")
scala_register_toolchains()

load("@io_bazel_rules_scala//scala:scala.bzl", "scala_repositories")
scala_repositories()

protobuf_version="09745575a923640154bcf307fba8aedff47f240a"
protobuf_version_sha256="416212e14481cff8fd4849b1c1c1200a7f34808a54377e22d7447efdf54ad758"

http_archive(
    name = "com_google_protobuf",
    url = "https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/archive/%s.tar.gz" % protobuf_version,
    strip_prefix = "protobuf-%s" % protobuf_version,
    sha256 = protobuf_version_sha256,
)

# bazel-skylib 0.8.0 released 2019.03.20 (https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel-skylib/releases/tag/0.8.0)
skylib_version = "0.8.0"
http_archive(
    name = "bazel_skylib",
    type = "tar.gz",
    url = "https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel-skylib/releases/download/{}/bazel-skylib.{}.tar.gz".format (skylib_version, skylib_version),
    sha256 = "2ef429f5d7ce7111263289644d233707dba35e39696377ebab8b0bc701f7818e",
)
```

`BUILD.bazel` file:

```
load("@io_bazel_rules_scala//scala:scala.bzl", "scala_library", "scala_binary", "scala_test")

scala_library(
    name = "pkg1",
    srcs = [
        "Main.scala"
    ]
)
```

bazel version:

```
$ bazel version
Bazelisk version: v1.0
Build label: 1.1.0
Build target: bazel-out/darwin-opt/bin/src/main/java/com/google/devtools/build/lib/bazel/BazelServer_deploy.jar
Build time: Mon Oct 21 08:47:13 2019 (1571647633)
Build timestamp: 1571647633
Build timestamp as int: 1571647633
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That version of rules_scala appears appears to be designed for the prior bazel version. [rules_scala#876](https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_scala/issues/876) is about this specific issue, and mentions another commit to try: [3404be0e3b3afda99a12724171d80283eaf2b1e7](https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_scala/commit/3404be0e3b3afda99a12724171d80283eaf2b1e7). You might also try [26cf9b74fc46f1e9a970c97837447549ed7257b6](https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_scala/commit/26cf9b74fc46f1e9a970c97837447549ed7257b6), which is master when I looked just now. You would replace the `rules_scala_version` value in the first line of the WORKSPACE with one of those commit SHA1 values.

For reference, the [java_common v0.29.1](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/0.29.1/skylark/lib/java_common.html#create_provider) docs mention create_provider, but the [java_common v1.0.0](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/1.0.0/skylark/lib/java_common.html) docs don't.